# Does orbital refer to a locus where the probability of finding an electron is maximum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

If I want to draw a certain circle or parabola, I will need an equation from which I can plot points on a polar or cartesian co-ordinate.

If orbitals refer to locus of equipotential points where the probability of finding an electron is maximum, there must be an equation for locus from which I will be able to plot points on cartesian or polar co-ordinate.

When I draw a circle after plotting all the points, I can say that its shape is 'round.' Likewise, If I have necessary equation for plotting points for the orbitals, then I can say that s orbital is 'spherical' and p orbital is 'dumbell shape.'

So, where's the equation of drawing the locus of s orbital or p orbital?

Comment: As an answer to the question you refered to, you have written: //Usually, however, the most useful graphical representation is not in an equation of the form r=f(θ,φ).// I don't want it to be the most useful graphical representation, I just want it for my own satisfaction.  If you don't know how to get an equation of form r=f(θ,φ), I am requesting you to unmark this question as 'duplicate'. And if you know, please, help me in this regard.

Comment: Trying to find a short-cut on understanding orbitals that lets you bypass the math is fraught with dangers. For instance, the locus of points where the probability of finding a 1s electron is highest exists *inside the nucleus* but the plots that you see on, say, Wikipedia show a spherical cloud thousands of times larger than the nucleus because the probability of finding the electron inside the nucleus is very small, it's just larger than at any other comparable volume. The plot shows the fun outside the nucleus because there are so many more comparable volumes at large radius.

Answer (score 0):

Typically textbooks depict the "shape" of the orbital by taking the region within which the electron has a 90 percent chance* of being found. The probability density function can be found by solving the Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom, then taking the resulting wavefunction and computing its squared magnitude.

*It could be any arbitrary probability, but the textbooks I own all say 90 percent.

Comment: //The probability density function can be found by solving the Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom// Can you please, give tell me where can I find complete solution of Schrodinger Equation?

Comment: @Hisab https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction

Comment: I want to plot points. So, I need a function r(θ,ϕ) out of the wave functions ψ(r,θ,ϕ). The link you provided discusses about ψ(r,θ,ϕ). But nowhere in the internet I coule find r(θ,ϕ) by which I could plot points in a polar co-ordinate. Please, help me in this regard.

Comment: @Hisab The core determiners of the orbitals' shapes are the spherical harmonics $Y^l_m(\theta,\phi)$. Plot these and you have the general orbital shapes, not to scale relative to each other.

Comment: // Plot these and you have the general orbital shapes//. How can I plot this? Please, give an answer elaborately.

Comment: @Hasib Let $r(\theta,\phi)=Y^l_m(\theta,\phi)$.

Comment: How can I plot Ylm(θ,ϕ)?

Comment: @Hisab Ignoring normalization, $Y^l_m(\theta,\phi) = P^l_m(\cos{\theta})e^{-im\phi}$, where the $P^l_m$ are the Legendre polynomials. This is a complex-valued function, so typically the real part is taken for plotting: $Re\; Y^l_m(\theta,\phi) = P^l_m(\cos{\theta})\cos{(m\phi)}$.

Comment: Just choosing to show "a 90% region" isn't enough to specify the region to use—you could show a 90% region on a Gaussian that includes all of the left tail (or all of the right tail) just fine, but statisticians use the one that is symmetric about the max. For orbitals the problem is more complicated still, because you need to ask yourself if you want to use  most probably volume (in the nucleus for 1s orbitals) or most probably radius (not in the nucleus even for 1s orbitals) or something still more sophisticated for the 'center' of your range.